# How to create connections from different IPs

Tags: vpn, ip

I want to have four connections which have different IPs on the same country from different locations so that system administrators can not detect the relation that all requests are coming from devices that are controlled by me.

If I have four VPNs, then some of them will be the same provider ( so similar IPs ) so that the system administrators will likely to recognize it. More, VPN providers have some companies for the service, and when they checked the website like mylocation.org, they will discover I have VPN connection.

I have mobile phones (utilizing cellular data) which have different IPs. Let's say that I have four instances in AWS. Can I send requests to the server from AWS instance via my mobile phone?

I will try to simplify my problem with the following example. The case I struggled with is getting banned from online games due to the same IP connection from different accounts. Also, they discover using VPNs (I have already tried nordVPN) and all regions in AWS have access limited from Cloudflare.

Is there any existing solution to this problem, can anybody guide me to overcome it?

Comment: How much are you willing to spend per month on this? Having a budget will help focus answers on options that are actually useable by you.

Comment: I can spend 50$ on each setup. What I mean by setup is 15$ for mobile phone cellular data, 35$ for aws elastic IP and ec2 instances. Yet, I could not manage the configure this setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HTTPS/SOCKS5 proxy on AWS. See for that for example the
[ec2_proxies project](https://github.com/vifreefly/ec2_proxies)
for creating on demand free HTTPS/SOCKS5 proxy servers using AWS Free Tier EC2 instances.

You may use [Tor project](https://www.torproject.org/),
with the limitation that it only works for TCP streams for any application
and with SOCKS support.
When using Tor, the server should only see the IP from the Tor exit node.
You could even
[Set a Specific Country in Tor](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Specific-Country-in-a-Tor-Browser).
The downside is that it's possible to find out that your connection is coming from Tor.

There are also many free Proxy servers on the Internet and sites that contain
lists of socks proxies, but these free proxies are usually not of good quality.

These are the options I know of.

Comment: I decided to use my mobile phone (with cellular data) as proxy server. There are some applications that claim it's possible to use phone as it. Yet, the port I have opened for the service is not open to connections. There exists lots of tutorials on wifi router but there is no solution provided for cellular network

Comment: Using a cellular hotspot requires static IPs and firewall configuration (or disable).